# Flutter: How to show unique header in StickyHeader or SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show unique header from JSON (Ex: "Header 1"; "Header 2"; "Header 3") like this:

[image]

this is JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "header": "Header 1",
    "line": "line 1 of Header 1"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 1",
    "line": "line 2 of Header 1"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 2",
    "line": "line 1 of Header 2"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 2",
    "line": "line 2 of Header 2"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 3",
    "line": "line 1 of Header 3"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 3",
    "line": "line 2 of Header 3"
  }
]
```

so pls help me, I am using the package `StickyHeader` but I think that `SliverAppBar` can also do it, this is main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/header_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers/widget.dart';

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  Future<List<Header>> getHeaderFromJson(BuildContext context) async {
    String jsonString = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/header.json');
    List<dynamic> raw = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    return raw.map((e) => Header.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Header')),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getHeaderFromJson(context),
            builder: (context, data) {
              List<Header> _header = data.data;
              return _header == null
                  ? Container()
                  : ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _header.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return StickyHeader(
                          header: Container(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: Text(_header[index].header), // I think this line needs to modify
                          ),
                          content: Column(
                            children: [Text(_header[index].line)],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that you are confused. But let me tell you one thing, the way you are setting up the widget is wrong, as per your requirements.

If you closely take a look at the data, this is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "header": "Header 1",
    "line": "line 1 of Header 1"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 1",
    "line": "line 2 of Header 1"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 2",
    "line": "line 1 of Header 2"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 2",
    "line": "line 2 of Header 2"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 3",
    "line": "line 1 of Header 3"
  },
  {
    "header": "Header 3",
    "line": "line 2 of Header 3"
  }
]
```

Now if you're looping through the data via your `ListView.builder`, the machine will print out one item at a time, hence you are seeing the output on your Device screen like that.

```
// Just do that and see for yourself, what the outcome is there
// suppose we name your array data as _data
_data.forEach((element){
  print(element["header"]);
  print(element["list"]);
});

/* The output you will get it like this only
Header 1
line 1 of Header 1
Header 1
line 2 of Header 1
Header 2
line 1 of Header 2
Header 2
line 2 of Header 2
Header 3
line 1 of Header 3
Header 3
line 2 of Header 3
*/
```

And this is how you are getting on your screen, isn't it? The machine is doing the job in this way.

**SOLUTION:** What is required for you to do is to organize the item, such that your `"header"` should contain all the `"line"` associated to the right `header` only. You can do it via creating your `Map` and store the data like this:

```
  Map _newData = {};
  
  // basic idea is, if the header is same, the value has all the lines 
  // aligned to it
  _data.forEach((element){
    if(_newData.containsKey(element["header"])){
      _newData[element["header"]].add(element["line"]);
    }else{
      _newData[element["header"]] = [element["line"]];
    }
  });
  
  print(_newData);

  //OUTPUT will come like this
  // {Header 1: [line 1 of Header 1, line 2 of Header 1], Header 2: [line 1 of Header 2, line 2 of Header 2], Header 3: [line 1 of Header 3, line 2 of Header 3]}
```

Can you the data now, `Header 1` has all the `line` associated to it, and so on.

So, now how we can achieve this in our app. I have not used any `StickyHeader` or something, with simple Flutter widgets, I have recreated your UI. See, and hope you can learn something new

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Used the data directly, since I don't have the API data
  List<Map> _data = [
    {
      "header": "Header 1",
      "line": "line 1 of Header 1"
    },
    {
      "header": "Header 1",
      "line": "line 2 of Header 1"
    },
    {
      "header": "Header 2",
      "line": "line 1 of Header 2"
    },
    {
      "header": "Header 2",
      "line": "line 2 of Header 2"
    },
    {
      "header": "Header 3",
      "line": "line 1 of Header 3"
    },
    {
      "header": "Header 3",
      "line": "line 2 of Header 3"
    }
  ];
  
  // This will give out our final widget with header and data
  Widget get myWidget{
    // Consists of all the Widgets
    List<Widget> _widget = [];
    
    // our new data to contain {"header": [line]}
    Map _newData = {};
    
    // adding the same to it
    _data.forEach((element){
      if(_newData.containsKey(element["header"])){
        _newData[element["header"]].add(element["line"]);
      }else{
        _newData[element["header"]] = [element["line"]];
      }
    });
    
    // now finally traversing through our _newData to add the widget accordingly
    _newData.forEach((k,v){
      // This will add the subitems of the particular Header
      List<Widget> _getWidget = [];
      
      // Adding header items to the Container
      _widget.add(
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Text(k, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
      ));
       
     // traversing through line array for a particular array 
     // And adding to the Widget with the border underline
      v.forEach((data){
        _getWidget.add(
          Text(data)
        ); 
        _getWidget.add(
          Divider(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey[300])
        );
      });
      
     // Finally adding the list of lines under the header
      _widget.add(
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: _getWidget
        )
      );
    });
    
    // returning the final widget in Column
    // Since our _widget is a list of widgets
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: _widget
    );
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
         height: double.infinity,
         width: double.infinity,
         child: this.myWidget
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**FINAL OUTCOME**

This is how, your app would look like:

[image: New Image]

Comment: Perfect answer! It not only solved my problem but also helped me to understand many things, Thank you xD

Comment: Thanks @Kel. I am glad that it worked out for you, and for learning part, this is what we are trying our best to do, i.e., **Make people understand what they are really trying to achieve**. I am happy with your response as well. Gave me a motivation too :)

Comment: I edited the post to ask more, hope you can help again :D

Comment: Maintain the Array like that, and then work on the UI @kel. Example `[{"header": "Header1", "line": "line 1 of header 1", "countrycode": "US", "assetsurl": "assets/icons/us.png"}]` This will simplify your task, and then you can make changes to the UI code accordingly. Hope that helps

Comment: I have no idea how to create the array like that, I [tried](https://i.imgur.com/sHcRYCB.jpg) but it doesn't seem right :(

Comment: So me what you get in `_header`, print it and show it to me @kel

Comment: I upload JSON file [here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/header.json?alt=media&token=9cb470be-a48e-4530-b498-2b9515539de2) then parse it to `_header`, after [print](https://i.imgur.com/dOliQLp.jpg) It seem doesn't look like `_data`, maybe I was wrong somewhere

Comment: I had some posts with a longer answer than this: D, but if you want, I'll create another post to make it easier for newbie like me to search ^^

Comment: That'd somehow help. Just create another question with **final requirement**, and share the link here. I will help you out. Before that, just let me know you know how to use assets in Flutter, right? Just confirming, else you will get confused. **If not, do a research on how to do that, and then proceed**

Comment: About assets, as far as I know, I rename images file same as data then access them like [this](https://i.imgur.com/T4P0QD9.jpg), it works fine for me :D

Comment: Just wanted to know for the confirmation. This looks fine. Go ahead, and frame your question please. Also, please show your updated `JSON Data` there. There might be people who will give some best answers to your question. I will also answer it :)

Comment: I created the final requirement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62777866/flutter-how-to-custom-header-from-json). Btw, thank you for your enthusiasm xD

Comment: Hey @Kel, I hope you will learn something out of it, and become better day by day. I have answered your another question. Go take a look :)