# Flutter: How to custom Header from JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a JSON file like this ([link API](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/page3.json?alt=media&token=726ee7f1-6b7e-4751-971f-1377e4026cd8)):

```
[
  {
    "continentName": "North America",
    "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/us/shiny/64.png",
    "countryCode": "US",
    "countryName": "United States"
  },
  {
    "continentName": "North America",
    "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/ca/shiny/64.png",
    "countryCode": "CA",
    "countryName": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "continentName": "South America",
    "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/br/shiny/64.png",
    "countryCode": "BR",
    "countryName": "Brazil"
  },
  {
    "continentName": "South America",
    "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/in/shiny/64.png",
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "countryName": "India"
  },
  {
    "continentName": "Europe",
    "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/gb/shiny/64.png",
    "countryCode": "GB",
    "countryName": "United Kingdom"
  },
  {
    "continentName": "Europe",
    "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/de/shiny/64.png",
    "countryCode": "DE",
    "countryName": "Germany"
  }
```

I want to show header of same "continentName" (Ex: North America; South America; Europe) like this

[image]

So pls help me, if possible to use `StickyHeader` or `SliverAppBar` then great, this is main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/page3_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/page3_services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page3 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page3State createState() => _Page3State();
}

class _Page3State extends State<Page3> {
  List<Header> _header = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    HeaderServices.getHeader().then((header) {
      setState(() {
        _header = header;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Header')),
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

> "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details". =.= ...........................................

Comment: Answered @Kel :). So good to see my country's flag [INDIA] in your app. Hahaha!

Comment: does this Header class already has the countries grouped by continent? in that case just as @Hakiza said I would recommend using the sticky_headers package to keep the header in the top when scrolling the slivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, we can see that there are more than one info related to a `continentName`, for example, for `North America` has `countryFlag`, `countryCode`, 'countryName' respectively, and that is unique. So we will keep our `newData` in this format

```
{
    North America: [
        [countryFlag, countryCode, countryName], 
        [countryFlag, countryCode, countryName]
    ]
}
...
```

So, this is how we will do that using our new `Map` which will store the value like the above representation

```
  Map _newMap = {};
  
  // new Map which will store the data
  // _data is the variable name which stores your JSON Array
  _data.forEach((elem){
    if(_newMap.containsKey(elem["continentName"])){
      _newMap[elem["continentName"]].add([elem["countryFlag"], elem["countryName"], elem["countryCode"]]);
    }else{
      // Array of arrays will be stored like this
      _newMap[elem["continentName"]] = [[elem["countryFlag"], elem["countryName"], elem["countryCode"]]];
    }
  });
  
  print(_newMap);

  /*
     OUTPUT
     {North America: [[https://www.countryflags.io/us/shiny/64.png, United States, US], [https://www.countryflags.io/ca/shiny/64.png, Canada, CA]], South America: [[https://www.countryflags.io/br/shiny/64.png, Brazil, BR], [https://www.countryflags.io/in/shiny/64.png, India, IN]], Europe: [[https://www.countryflags.io/gb/shiny/64.png, United Kingdom, GB], [https://www.countryflags.io/de/shiny/64.png, Germany, DE]]}
  */
```

See that! So, the idea is for every `continentName`, we can have array of arrays which will contain different item to be shown under a specific `continentName`

With that, here is final solution for you:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Map> _data = [
    {
      "continentName": "North America",
      "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/us/shiny/64.png",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "countryName": "United States"
    },
    {
      "continentName": "North America",
      "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/ca/shiny/64.png",
      "countryCode": "CA",
      "countryName": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "continentName": "South America",
      "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/br/shiny/64.png",
      "countryCode": "BR",
      "countryName": "Brazil"
    },
    {
      "continentName": "South America",
      "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/in/shiny/64.png",
      "countryCode": "IN",
      "countryName": "India"
    },
    {
      "continentName": "Europe",
      "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/gb/shiny/64.png",
      "countryCode": "GB",
      "countryName": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "continentName": "Europe",
      "countryFlag": "https://www.countryflags.io/de/shiny/64.png",
      "countryCode": "DE",
      "countryName": "Germany"
    }
  ];
  
  // This will give out our final widget with header and data
  Widget get myWidget{
    // Consists of all the Widgets
    List<Widget> _widget = [];
    
    Map _newMap = {};
  
    // new Map which will store the data
    _data.forEach((elem){
      if(_newMap.containsKey(elem["continentName"])){
        _newMap[elem["continentName"]].add([elem["countryFlag"], elem["countryName"], elem["countryCode"]]);
      }else{
        // Array of arrays will be stored like this
        _newMap[elem["continentName"]] = [[elem["countryFlag"], elem["countryName"], elem["countryCode"]]];
      }
    });
    
    _newMap.forEach((k,v){
      List<Widget> _subHeaderItems = [];
      
      _widget.add(
        Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Text(k, textAlign: TextAlign.center)
        )
      );
      
      // We get the item like this item => [countryName, countryCode, countryFlag]
      v.forEach((item){
        _subHeaderItems.add(
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width: 10.0),
              Image.network(
                item[0],
                width: 30.0,
                height: 20.0
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 20.0),
              Text(item[2]),
              SizedBox(width: 35.0),
              Text(item[1]),
            ]
          )
        );
        
        _subHeaderItems.add(
          Divider(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey[300])
        );
      });
      
      _widget.add(
        Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
         children: _subHeaderItems
        )
      );
    });
    
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: _widget
    );
  }
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
         height: double.infinity,
         width: double.infinity,
         child: this.myWidget
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**RESULT YOU WILL GET**

[image: Result Image]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Yeah! It works! That is really a BIG HELP for those who are new to coding like me. Thank you very much xD

Comment: Happy to help @Kel. Will be waiting to see you helping people here regarding any doubts on Flutter :)

Comment: Well done, It basically solved my issue :D. Btw, in case I want to further improve its UI/UX with [Sticky Headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers), is there any way we can use Sticky Headers for the header with this code?

Comment: Yes, but that thing, I leave upto you. Since, the basic problem was handle the case of our  `JSON Data`. When you are done with this, it is only about using different Widgets. Play with it. :) All the best

Comment: I wanted to implement sidebar sticky header using flutter_sticky_header plugin and show dynamic data which comes from the api and @Alok your answer is really helped. Thank you very much:)